# Custom play button for HTML5 videos

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, html5-video

I have a web page with multiple videos. Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

- A custom play button for each one of them.
- When clicking on the play button, I want the button to disappear.
- When the video ended, I want the play button to appear again.

I haven't found information about this specific need. I'm also not very familiar with JS so your help here would be extra appreciated

Comment: The `<video></video>` tag has `controls` attribute by default you can use it , Don't you know about it or you want to create your own controls ?

Comment: Here is an example : 

` <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>



<video width="420" height="340" controls>
  <source src="yourvideourl" type="video/mp4">
</video>

</body>
</html>`

Comment: Thank you :) I'm indeed looking to create a custom play button

Comment: I'll add a working sample, just wait a min :)

Comment: @Matan you need to clarify your _"looking to create a custom play button"_ . **(1)** Do you have an existing graphic ready to be clicked, and just want to know how to trigger some video element's Play function?... **(2)** Or are you asking how to actually draw a graphic? Is that why `css` is tagged, because you're using CSS shapes or something?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve custom buttons by calling the html  and styling with css. For disappearing onclick, just add an event listener for javascript using

```
document.getElementById('BUTTON ID').addEventListener('click',function(){ document.getElementById('BUTTON ID').style.display = 'none';});
```

reappearing onclick will have to make use of video tags built-in controls such as

```
document.getElementById('VIDEO ID').onended = function(){
document.getElementById('VIDEO ID').style.display = 'block';
}
```

EDIT RUNNABLE SNIPPET--

```js
document.getElementById('press').addEventListener('click', function(){
document.getElementById('vid').play();
document.getElementById('press').style.display = 'none';
});
document.getElementById('vid').onended = function(){
document.getElementById('press').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
#press{
background-color: blue;
color: red;
}
```

```html
<video id="vid" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video><br>
<button id='press'>Play Video</button>
```

Comment: upvote if this helped you. Ask about anything and i'll do my best to answer.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I'm missing something - but how do I customize the original HTML5 play button?

Comment: use the css to change background color, font color, border, etc, if that's what you're asking. You can also make the edges circular or more rounded by changing the border-radius

Comment: For each video, you could additionally add a button for each one

Comment: @Matan _"how do I customize the original HTML5 play button?"_  not a good idea as you have to change it according to each browsers rules (the HTML5 play button for iOS needs different code to the HTML5 play button in Edge etc). The easiest thing is to create your own icons (images?) and have each browser use those same images. So remove HTML5 `controls` and give your image an ID and a click listener to run some JS function, then in JS you have a function to play the video element by ID according to clicked image ID.